# Ruby Signal.trap exit(-1)

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, command-line

I am trying to unit test a command line tool, that uses `trollop`. One of the calls it makes to `trollop` is `Trollop::die "my message"`, which underneath calls `exit(-1)`
Now, this makes my unit tests to fail, because this kills rake - I've tried using `Signal.trap` to trap the signal, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Does anyone have any idea on how to trap this kind of exit code ?

Comment: `exit` is just a method in the [`Kernel` module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) so maybe you can monkey patch your way around the problem.

Comment: How do you use Signal.trap? Post some code plz.

Comment: Mu's solution will work.  Just put a `def exit(*args); nil; end` in the test suite to stop #exit from doing anything at all.